# How to diagonalise sparse csr 1D-matrix (vector) in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

[Short version]

Is there an equivalent to numpy.diagflat() in scipy.sparse? Or any way to 'flatten' a sparse matrix made dense?

[Long version]

I have a sparse matrix (mathematically a vector), x_f, that I need to diagonalise (i.e. create a square matrix with the values of the x_f vector on the diagonal).

```
x_f
Out[59]: 
<35021x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 47 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I've tried 'diags' from the scipy.sparse module. (I've also tried 'spdiags', but it's just a more fancy version of 'diags', which I don't need.) I've tried it with every combination of [csr or csc format], [original or transposed vector] and [.todense() or .toarray()], but I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: Different number of diagonals and offsets.
```

With sparse.diags the default offset is 0, and what I'm trying to do is to *only* put numbers on the main diagonal (which is the default), so getting this error means it's not working as I want it to.

Here are examples of the original and transposed vector with .todense() and .toarray() respectively:

```
x_f_original.todense()
Out[72]: 
matrix([[  0.00000000e+00],
        [  0.00000000e+00],
        [  0.00000000e+00],
        ..., 
        [  0.00000000e+00],
        [  1.03332178e-17],
        [  0.00000000e+00]])

x_f_transposed.toarray()
Out[83]: 
array([[  0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
          0.00000000e+00,   1.03332178e-17,   0.00000000e+00]])
```

The following code works, but takes about 15 seconds to run:

```
x_f_diag = sparse.csc_matrix(np.diagflat(x_f.todense()))
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to make it more efficient or just a better way to do this?

[Disclaimer]

This is my first question here. I hope I did it right and apologise for anything that's unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [106]: x_f = sparse.random(1000,1, .1, 'csr')
In [107]: x_f
Out[107]: 
<1000x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I can use it in `sparse.diags` if turn it into a 1d dense array.

```
In [108]: M1=sparse.diags(x_f.A.ravel()).tocsr()
In [109]: M1
Out[109]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Or I can make it a (1,1000) matrix, and use a list as the offset:

```
In [110]: M2=sparse.diags(x_f.T.A,[0]).tocsr()
In [111]: M2
Out[111]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

`diags` takes a dense diagonal, not a sparse.  This is stored as is, so I have use the further `.tocsr` to remove 0s etc.

```
In [113]: sparse.diags(x_f.T.A,[0])
Out[113]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
```

So either way I am matching the shape of diagonal with the number of offsets (scalar or 1).

A direct mapping to `csr` (or `csc`) is probably faster.

With this column shape, the `indices` attribute doesn't tell us anything.

```
In [125]: x_f.indices
Out[125]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

but transform that to `csc` (this maps the `indptr` onto `indices`)

```
In [126]: x_f.tocsc().indices
Out[126]: 
array([  2,  15,  26,  32,  47,  56,  75,  82,  96,  99, 126, 133, 136,
       141, 145, 149, ... 960, 976], dtype=int32)
In [127]: idx=x_f.tocsc().indices

In [128]: M3 = sparse.csr_matrix((x_f.data, (idx, idx)),(1000,1000))
In [129]: M3
Out[129]: 
<1000x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Comment: Thank you. What do the capital letters do? `A.ravel` and `T.A`? (It's tricky to google.)

Comment: T is for transpose.  A is for `toarray`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following constructor:

> ```
> csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])
> ```
>
> where `data`, `row_ind` and `col_ind` satisfy the relationship
>   `a[row_ind[k], col_ind[k]] = data[k]`.

**Demo (COO Matrix):**

```
from scipy.sparse import random, csr_matrix, coo_matrix

In [142]: M = random(10000, 1, .005, 'coo')

In [143]: M
Out[143]:
<10000x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 50 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [144]: M2 = coo_matrix((M.data, np.diag_indices(len(M.data))), (len(M.data), len(M.data)))

In [145]: M2
Out[145]:
<50x50 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 50 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [146]: M2.todense()
Out[146]:
matrix([[ 0.1559936 ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.28984266,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.21381431, ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        ...,
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.23100531,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.13789309,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.73827   ]])
```

---

**Demo (CSR matrix):**

```
In [112]: from scipy.sparse import random, csr_matrix

In [113]: M = random(10000, 1, .005, 'csr')

In [114]: M
Out[114]:
<10000x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 50 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [137]: M2 = csr_matrix((M.data, np.diag_indices(len(M.data))), (len(M.data), len(M.data)))

In [138]: M2
Out[138]:
<50x50 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
        with 50 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [139]: M2.todense()
Out[139]:
matrix([[ 0.45661992,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.42428401,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.99484544, ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        ...,
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.80880579,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.46292628,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.56363196]])
```

If you need a dense matrix:

```
In [147]: np.diagflat(M.data)
Out[147]:
array([[ 0.1559936 ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.28984266,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.21381431, ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       ...,
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.23100531,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.13789309,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.73827   ]])
```

Comment: Thank you! (I tried making x_f a coo matrix and then using: `x_f_diag = sparse.csc_matrix((x_f.data,(x_f.row, x_f.row)), shape=(for_size,for_size))`, which also works :)

Comment: I slept on this and realised that the CSR solution won't actually do what I need it to. Because I need a 10000x10000 diagonal matrix with the values from the sparse vector in the right place, but this gives me a 50x50 matrix with just the values from the x_f vector. The coo solution in my first comment will work though. (Where for size equals `x_f.shape[0]`, not `len(x_f.data)`.)